# Increase number of connections per socket

Tags: networking, freebsd, tcp, socket

How do I increase the number of connections each socket can accept?

I know that you can increase the total number of connections using:

```
# sysctl kern.ipc.somaxconn=4096
```

But each connection is then still limited to 128.

How do I increase the total connections per socket?

Comment: what is the output of: `sudo sysctl -a | grep somax` and what server software are you using?

Comment: sysctl -a | grep somax
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 500
uname -a
FreeBSD wtllab-resourced-1.phaedrus.sandvine.com 8.1-RELEASE-p2 FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE-p2 #0: Tue Mar 29 17:10:37 UTC 2011     root@lab-dnsv6-1.phaedrus.sandvine.com:/usr/d2/obj/usr/d2/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

Comment: Why is there a [tag:linux] tag on this, then?

Comment: removed linux tag

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer on another thread, seems like this is specifically an application issue. [FreeBSD Listen Queue Overflows - can't increase max queue size](https://serverfault.com/questions/443399/freebsd-listen-queue-overflows-cant-increase-max-queue-size)